# I need help simplifying this fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{(\frac{1}{2})}{(\frac{2 + \sqrt{3}}{2})}$$

I've tried solving this on my own for a while but I can't seem to get the right answer. I'm stuck.

Comment: Is it $$\frac{(\frac{1}{2})}{(\frac{2 + \sqrt{3}}{2})}$$ or $$ \frac{(\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2 + \sqrt{3}})}{2}?$$

Comment: it's the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\Large {\frac{(\frac{1}{2})}{(\frac{2 + \sqrt{3}}{2})} = \overset{\text{flip and multiply}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{2 + \sqrt{3}}}} = \frac{1}{2 + \sqrt{3}} = \overset{\text{multiply by} \frac{2 - \sqrt{3}}{2 - \sqrt{3}}}{\frac{2 - \sqrt{3}}{(2 + \sqrt{3})(2 - \sqrt{3})}} \\ \Large{= 2 - \sqrt{3}} $$

Answer (score 0):

The usual method from removing such radical expressions as $2+\sqrt{3}$ from the denominator is by multiplying the top and bottom of your fraction by the conjugate $2-\sqrt{3}$, taking advantage of the fact that $(2+\sqrt{3})(2-\sqrt{3}) = 2^2 - (\sqrt{3})^2 = 1$.

Comment: Wow thanks I totally forgot about that.

Comment: @user3709169, the method is known as [rationalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalisation_%28mathematics%29).